# Dynamic namedRange, Trying to print only cells with data in them

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

```
function readNamedRange() {
    var app = SpreadsheetApp;
    var activeSheet = app.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
    var listDown = activeSheet.getRange("listDown");
    var result = activeSheet.getRange("listDown").getValues();
}
```

In the above code, my active sheet contains a namedRange which has the entire B column set to the namedRange called **listDown**. Cells B1 to B10 have data 1 through 10 in them.
I am trying to print only data cells with values in them using both for loop and an if statement inside it. 
I have tried the following logic given below:

```
for(var i=0; i <result.length; i++){
 if(result.length[i] != "" && result.length[i] != undefined ){
  console.log(result); 
}else{
 console.log("namedRange is empty");
}
}
```

**My above logic is not complete and I am unable to understand how to do it.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to show the values of cells except for the empty cells at the log.

For this, how about this modification?

#### Modification points:

- `listDown` is not used in your script.
- The value retrieved by `getValues()` is 2 dimensional array. And your range is one column.

  - In this case, each value can be retrieved by `result[i][0]`.
- In your script, `result.length[i]` always becomes `undefined`.
- At `console.log(result)`, all values of `result` is shown.
- In your case, `result[i][0] != ""` can be used for the if statement.

When above points are reflected to your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

```
function readNamedRange() {
  var activeSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var result = activeSheet.getRange("listDown").getValues();
  for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
    if (result[i][0] != "") {  // Modified
      console.log(result[i][0]); // Modified
    } else {
      console.log("namedRange is empty");
    }
  }
}
```

#### References:

- [getValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues)
- [Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array)

### Added:

- You want to show the values of only cells except for the empty cells.

For this, how about the following modified script?

- The script in `else` was removed.
- In order to reduce the process cost, `var end = activeSheet.getLastRow()` is used for the for loop.

#### Modified script:

```
function readNamedRange() {
  var activeSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var result = activeSheet.getRange("listDown").getValues();
  var end = activeSheet.getLastRow();
  for (var i = 0; i < end; i++) {
    if (result[i][0] != "") {
      console.log(result[i][0]); 
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the above code.
But new issues and problems arise after this, the goal was to print only cells with data inside it.
In the log this code will also print 990 cells with the above statement in the else section.
I placed a **break** to change that, but now if I leave a space and type any data it will not be printed anymore.

Comment: @Adam Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. From your script, I thought that you want to show `namedRange is empty` for the empty cell. You want to show the values of only cells except for the empty cells. From your replying, I understood like this. For this, I added one more modified script. Could you please confirm it? In that script, the values of only cells except for the empty cells are shown.

Comment: Thank you for the above answer. I apologize as my question was not adequately set. 
I just started using appscript and I am finding it quite confusing, my goal with this above snippet is to connect the above data with an output popup box which will then create a dropdown.

Comment: @Adam Thank you for replying. No problem. By the way, can I ask you about your situation? If your issue in your this question was not resolved yet, please tell me. I would like to think of the issue.

Comment: I am working for a company so I am unable to give out the information at the moment. The idea is to have a User type in data in a list and then have that data be printed into a list inside a dialog box popup (html).

Comment: @Adam Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. I have not asked about your future question of `The idea is to have a User type in data in a list and then have that data be printed into a list inside a dialog box popup (html).`. I had asked whether [your this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61906664) was resolved by my proposed answer. Because I answered for your this question. If my answer didn't resolve your question, I have to modify it. Unfortunately, from your replying, I couldn't understand whether your question was resolved.

Comment: Yes thank you very much, your above answered has solved the question I had posted.

Comment: @Adam Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.