# Updating or inserting data from a Spreadsheet into a Dialog box inside a dropdown

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

**Goal**: The purpose is that a sheet will contain information, this information is placed inside a namedrange, the namedrange will be dynamic (the entire column is given a namedrange).
I created a html popup which contains a dropdown list. This dropdown list must contain the list of information from the namedrange.

I am unable to understand how this is to be done. Here is the code below:

```
   function fncOpenMyDialog() {
  var htmlDlg = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('HTML_myHtml')
      .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME)
      .setWidth(200)
      .setHeight(150);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
      .showModalDialog(htmlDlg, 'New File');
};

function onInstall(e) {
  onOpen(e);
}

function onOpen(e) {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.createMenu('New')
  .addItem('New Save File Extension','fncOpenMyDialog')
  .addToUi();
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
    <select name="nameYouWant" placeholde="File Type">
  <option value="something">Word</option>
  <option value="anything">MS Excel</option>
  <option value="anything">MS Powerpoint</option>
  <option value="anything">MS Slides</option>
  </select>

<hr/>
<p>Choose a file, which will then be saved into your Google Drive.</p>

<button onmouseup="closeDia()">Close</button>
<button onmouseup="onOpen()">Save</button>

<script>
  window.closeDia = function() {
    google.script.host.close();
  };
  window.saveDia = function() {
  onOpen();
  };
</script>
  </body>
</html>
```

As you can see in my html file, that the extensions are currently hardcoded. 
I am trying to make this dynamic, how do I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to put the values to the dropdown list by retrieving from the named range of the Spreadsheet.

  - In this case, is the named range the same with [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61906664/7108653)?

For this, how about this answer?

### Modification points:

- From `google.script.host.close()`, I understood that the HTML file of `HTML_myHtml` is included in the Google Apps Script project. By this, I would like to propose to achieve your goal using `google.script.run`.
- If the named range is the same with [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61906664/7108653), you can use it by modifying a little.

When above points are reflected to your script, it becomes as follows.

### Modified script:

#### HTML and JavaScript side: `HTML_myHtml`

Please modify `HTML_myHtml` as follows.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <base target="_top">
</head>

<body>
    <select id="select" name="nameYouWant" placeholde="File Type"></select>
    <hr />
    <p>Choose a file, which will then be saved into your Google Drive.</p>
    <button onmouseup="closeDia()">Close</button>
    <button onmouseup="onOpen()">Save</button>
    <script>
        google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(v => {
            const obj = document.getElementById("select");
            v.forEach(e => {
                const option = document.createElement("option");
                option.text = e;
                option.value = e;
                obj.appendChild(option);
            });
        }).readNamedRange();

        window.closeDia = function() {
            google.script.host.close();
        };

        window.saveDia = function() {
            onOpen();
        };
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

#### Google Apps Script side: `Code.gs`

At above HTML, `readNamedRange()` is used. So please put the following script. If you have the same function names, please modify them. In this script, the values are retrieved from the named range of `listDown`, and sent to HTML side using `google.script.run`.

```
function readNamedRange() {
  var activeSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var result = activeSheet.getRange("listDown").getValues();
  var end = activeSheet.getLastRow();
  var values = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < end; i++) {
    if (result[i][0] != "") {
      values.push(result[i][0]);
    }
  }
  return values;
}
```

### Note:

- About `window.saveDia = function() {onOpen()};`, unfortunately, I couldn't understand about what you want to do.

### Reference:

- [Class google.script.run](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run)

Comment: Thank you very much, Now my popup html dialog box receives the listDown data which was inside a namedRange.

Comment: @Adam Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved.